# Mathematica Function Definition to Latex?

Tags: latex

Suppose I have a function defined:

```
g[z_]:=Sum[Sin[z/k!],{k,0,infinity}]
```

And I want to export the following Latex based on only the function definition

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{z}{k!}\right)$$

Is it possible to do this in Mathematica? If so, how? Ideally it would work for any arbitrary function, or at least as often as possible.

Comment: I'd check out [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
g[z_] := Sum[Sin[z/k!], {k, 0, Infinity}]
g[z] // TeXForm
```

output is

```
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sin \left(\frac{z}{k!}\right).
```

However $g(z)$ will be simplified, for example `g[z_] := z+z` will yield $2z$. If you want to avoid that just use `g[z_] := Holdform[z+z]`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it select the equation and copy it as latex. It can be pasted in the latex editor as an equation. A picture is attached for references
[image]

Comment: This helps, but I need this process automated since I'll be doing it for several hundred equations.

Comment: You can also use TeXForm[] command available in Mathematica to get the Latex code of the equation.